SQLModel relationship through two foreign keys
Can I make a relationship with table C, which contains a foreign key to table B, which contains a foreign key to table A, from C to A? Something like the following:
class A(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    b_id: int | None = Field(default=None, foreign_key="b.id")

    b: 'B' = Relationship(back_populates='as')
    c: 'C' = Relationship() # Somehow have this automatically populated through b.c_id?

class B(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: id | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    c_id: int | None = Field(default=None, foreign_key='c.id)

    as: list[A] = Relationship(back_populates='b')
    c: 'C' = Relationship(back_populates='bs')

class C(SQLModel, table=True):
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    
    bs: list[B] = Relationship(back_populates='c')

I'm not even sure where to start with this. I tried just doing it and it threw an error for no foreign keys for A.c.

You have a mistake in c_id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True). It should be c_id: int | None = Field(default=None, foreign_key="c.id")

Try this approach: c: 'C' = Relationship(sa_relationship=RelationshipProperty("C", secondary="b", primaryjoin="b.c.id == A.b_id", secondaryjoin="C.id == b.c.c_id", viewonly=True))

SQLModel library does not automatically populate these relationships. So you need to explicitly define the relationships and then manually access them.

Define the models with relationships

Access relationships manually:
from sqlmodel import Session, create_engine, select
Create an SQLite database in memory (for testing purposes)
engine = create_engine("sqlite://")
Create the tables
SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)
Example of inserting data
with Session(engine) as session:
# Create a C instance
c_instance = C()
session.add(c_instance)
session.commit()
# Create a B instance linked to C
b_instance = B(c_id=c_instance.id)
session.add(b_instance)
session.commit()

# Create an A instance linked to B
a_instance = A(b_id=b_instance.id)
session.add(a_instance)
session.commit()

Query the database and access relationships
with Session(engine) as session:
a_instance = session.exec(select(A)).first()
b_instance = a_instance.b
c_instance = b_instance.c
print(f"A -> B ID: {b_instance.id}, B -> C ID: {c_instance.id}")


